# How to make the function getch() in c ignore backspace and enter as characters

Tags: c

i making a password program that hides the user input but when i press backspace to erase a charactere or enter to finish the input it register it as a character

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(){
  char pass[100],gt;
  char password[5]="123456";
  int i;
ps:
  printf("enter password:\n");
  while(gt != '\n') {
    if(pass == password)
      printf("access granted :\n");
    else {
      printf("access denied\n");
      fflush(stdin);
      goto ps;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior.  `pass == password` compares pointer addresses, *not* the contents pointed to.  You want `strcmp` or `memcmp` for that.  I believe the function `getc` will do what you want.  `getch` can mean different things (depends on system/library used) as it is not a standard function and is a different beast entirely.

Comment: Also: `gt` is not initialized before use. `"123456"` needs 7 bytes, not 5. The `goto` usage can be refactored and eliminated. You never actually read from stdin.

Comment: How did you even manage to get this to compile? It is invalid C in multiple ways.

Comment: An advantage of using MS VC's `_getch()` is that it does not echo to the console, so you can output an asterisk.

Comment: The ISO C standard library does not have a function `getch`. You appear to be referring to a platform-specific function. However, it is unclear which platform you are referring to, because there exist several platforms which implement a platform-specific function `getch`. For this reason, please [edit] your question to specify to which platform (i.e. operating system and compiler) your question applies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has some issue. The variable `gt` is not initialized before being used in the while loop. This can result in undefined behavior. The while loop condition is checking if `gt` is **not equal** to the newline character `\n`, but the loop isn't actually reading any input from the user. This can result in an infinite loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>

int main() {
    char password[] = "123456";
    char input[100];
    int i = 0;
    printf("Enter password:\n");

    // Disable echoing of input characters
    struct termios old, new;
    tcgetattr(fileno(stdin), &old);
    new = old;
    new.c_lflag &= ~ECHO;
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &new);

    // Read input until newline character is encountered
    char c = getchar();
    while (c != '\n' && i < 99) {
        if (c == 127) {  // Handle backspace character
            if (i > 0) {
                i--;
                printf("\b \b");
            }
        } else {
            input[i++] = c;
            printf("*");
        }
        c = getchar();
    }
    input[i] = '\0';

    // Restore original terminal settings
    tcsetattr(fileno(stdin), TCSANOW, &old);

    // Compare input to password
    if (strcmp(input, password) == 0) {
        printf("\nAccess granted.\n");
    } else {
        printf("\nAccess denied.\n");
        main(); // Restart the program
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: NOTE: this is a posix solution.  If I had to guess based on the `getch` in the question, that the user is on Windows?

Comment: @Jason: The curses library for UNIX also has a `getch` function. See [this documentation](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/curs_getch.3x.html). Therefore, the question is unclear, because it is referring to platform-specific functionality without specifying to which platform the question applies.

Comment: In your answer, you wrote: `"This can result in undefined behavior."` -- I disagree with the word "can". In this case, this **is** undefined behavior, according to [§6.3.2.1 ¶2 sentence 4 of the ISO C11 standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p2).

Comment: sn01, `char c = getchar();` better as `int c = getchar();` as `getchar()` return 257 different values.  Also, consider what should happen when `EOF` is returned.